# Integration to multiple Content Management Systems?

Tags: cms-integration

Can you Integrate your Civi CRM into multiple Content Management Systems? like WordPress and Drupal at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot depends on what sort of integration you are looking for.

CiviCRM uses the CMS to manage logins and theming so its not really possible to integrate with more than one system in that sense.  CiviCRM sits on top of a single CMS.

However, you can display forms on multiple different platforms linked to a common CiviCRM.  You can do that in platform-specific ways (eg webforms on Drupal, Caldera Forms on WordPress) or more platform-independent ways, like [inlay](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/inlay).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that explains a lot